# connect an android application to a JEE6 application

Tags: android, jakarta-ee

I want to connect my web application (developped with EJB 3.1 and JSF2.0) , to an android application. In the first application I'm planificating an intervention to each employee and I want to communicate a notification to his android device. Please help me to find the best way to connect them.

Answer (score 0):

I think GCM is generally the best approach for this.  http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I choosed to use web services.